# Ответ списком на сообщение в Telegram

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Как можно отправить весь список целиком пользователю с форматированием?
Методом `bot.send_message` не отправляет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отправить пользователю красиво отформатированный список в читаемом виде можно в формате JSON. Делается это в три этапа: формирование строки с JSON, затем преобразование в HTML и собственно отправка. Вот код:

```
text = json.dumps(ваш_список, ensure_ascii=False, sort_keys=True, indent=2)
data = '<pre>' + html.escape(text, quote=False) + '</pre>'
bot.send_message(ид_получателя, data, parse_mode='HTML')
```